# What is meant by quadratic factor optimal in Cheeger Inequality?

Tags: spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Given a *Cheeger inequality*,
$$2h_{G}\geq\lambda_{G}\geq\dfrac{h_{G}^{2}}{2}$$.

Cheeger inequality guarantees that the cut
resulting from this efficient algorithm has the Cheeger ratio within a
quadratic factor of the optimum.

My question is:

What is meant by 'within  a quadratic factor of the optimum'?

I understand that $h_{G}\le2\sqrt{h_{G}}$. Thus, is the quadratic factor of optimal is influenced by the $\sqrt{h_{G}}$? And, does the constant '2' affect 'within a quadratic factor of optimality'. In another word, if the constant is replaced by another number such as '4', how does the optimality affected?

I am not a mathematician, thus I am not familiar with this concept. 
But as my work do involve some spectral clustering optimization, I need to understand this terminology.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which efficient algorithm are you using?

Comment: @Neal I using motif-based spectral clustering method. [link] (http://snap.stanford.edu/higher-order/index.html). Saw the explanation on 'within quadratic factor of optimal' in the supplemetary materials. But could not understand fully.